# SwitchPreference Not turning Off

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to turn off switch preference when a condition is met, I have written code but still, it is not turning it off. How to fix?

Where p1 is string, getting return from path();. I could able to show Toast, but .ischecked(false) not working.

```
 enableapp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                if (!enableapp.isChecked()) {
                    path();
                    if (p1.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(FinalSettings.this, "Your Device Does not Support", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        enableapp.setChecked(false);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
enableapp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            if (!enableapp.isChecked()) {
                if (path().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(FinalSettings.this, "Your Device Does not Support", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    enableapp.setChecked(false);

                }
```

`p1` - non initialize, so the condition is not satisfied.

Comment: No change. Still same issue.

Comment: i simplified to check but still no benefit.